# colors in legend do not match graph colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to make customized legends showing only some of the lines plotted. However, the color in the legend does not always match the color of the plotted line. In the example legend 1 and legend 2 are fine, but legend 3 should show blue and green, not blue and orange. See attached image. How can I fix this?

[image: legend 3 should be blue (0) and green (2)]

Here is a mwe which I used to generate the image, but note that in the real program the plot function is not directly accessible and loaded from a different file. Also, the plot function should not be modified as it is used in other programs as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def my_plot_function(x,y,ax):
    #do complicated stuff here, manipulating y for example
    ax.plot(x,y)

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

my_plot_function(x, x, ax)
my_plot_function(x, x**2, ax)
my_plot_function(x, x**3, ax)
my_plot_function(x, x**4, ax)

lines = ax.get_lines()
print(lines[0])
print(lines[1])
print(lines[2])
print(lines[3])

fig.legend(lines, labels=range(4), loc=1, title="legend 1")
fig.legend([lines[0],lines[1]], labels=["0","1"], loc=2, title="legend 2")
fig.legend([lines[0],lines[2]], labels=["0","2"], loc=3, title="legend 3")
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**
To clarify what I was asking for: Plotting needs to be done by `my_plot_function` which is defined in a separate file and may not be modified. Thus I cannot pass it additional keywords such as `label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the docs of figure.legend we can see that labels has to be used with handles (and the other way). You must put both handles and labels or none of them.

This works

```
fig.legend(lines, range(4), loc=1, title="legend 1")
fig.legend((lines[0],lines[1]), ("0","1"), loc=2, title="legend 2")
fig.legend((lines[0],lines[2]), ("0","2"), loc=3, title="legend 3")
```

and this works

```
fig.legend(handles=lines, labels=range(4), loc=1, title="legend 1")
fig.legend(handles=(lines[0],lines[1]), labels=("0","1"), loc=2, title="legend 2")
fig.legend(handles=(lines[0],lines[2]), labels=("0","2"), loc=3, title="legend 3")
```

Answer (score 5):

I would approach the problem slightly differently. In cases like yours, I would always recommend to pass the legend entry while plotting using the `label` keyword. Then, to use selected legends, you can use `get_legend_handles_labels()` and then pass the required items to `fig.legend()`. You do not have to specify the `handles` and `labels` arguments. But if you specify one (like you did for `labels`), you should also specify the other or else you get a warning

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot(x,y,ax):
    ax.plot(x,y)

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, x, label='0')
ax.plot(x, x**2, label='1')
ax.plot(x, x**3, label='2')
ax.plot(x, x**4, label='3')
ax.legend(loc=1, title='legend 1')

h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

fig.legend([h[0],h[1]], [l[0], l[1]], loc=2, title="legend 2")
fig.legend([h[0],h[2]], [l[0], l[2]], loc=3, title="legend 3")
plt.show()
```

[image]

An alternative approach answering @gboffi comment below is following where you don't use the global legend to extract the values.

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

l0, = ax.plot(x, x, label='0')
l1, = ax.plot(x, x**2, label='1')
l2, = ax.plot(x, x**3, label='2')
l3, = ax.plot(x, x**4, label='3')

fig.legend([l0, l1], [l0.get_label(), l1.get_label()], loc=2, title="legend 2")
fig.legend([l0, l2], [l0.get_label(), l2.get_label()], loc=3, title="legend 3")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I have upvoted but... say I don't want a _global_ legend (the one you used to get the handles and the labels) but only two legends, with lines 0, 1 and with lines 2, 3 (my hypothetical use case, not repeating infos, is more realistic than the OP's one).   Is it still possible to use a similar approach?

Comment: @gboffi: If I understood you correctly, one hack is to replace either the first or the second `fig.legend()` by `ax.legend()`.. This will replace the axis level global legend with 4 enteries. So you use it just to extract the handles and legends and then overwrite it

Comment: @gboffi: I have added an alternative answer. Let me know if it addresses your point

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer, but it does not quite solve my problem. I edited by question to make it more clear that plotting needs to be done by the `my_plot_function` which I cannot modify. Thus I cannot use `ax.plot` directly or pass labels. Anyways, I like the `.get_label()` approach for when I have a line handle already.

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code, I get a warning from `legend.py`:

```
UserWarning: You have mixed positional and keyword arguments, some input may be discarded.
  warnings.warn("You have mixed positional and keyword "...
```

This is probably the reason why it's not working. You need to add the `handles` in your legend calls. I.e.

```
fig.legend(handles=[lines[0],lines[1]],...
```

By the way, it's a good practice to assign a label when the plot is created.

```
ax.plot(x, y, label='some label')
```

Then you can call

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
```

and use them in the legend like so

```
fig.legend(handles=(handles[0],handles[2]), labels=(labels[0],labels[2]),...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am used to be mixing both. Should change that habit and read warnings more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Use `handles` keyword argument:

```
fig.legend(handles=lines, labels=range(4), loc=1, title="legend 1")
fig.legend(handles=[lines[0],lines[1]], labels=["0","1"], loc=2, title="legend 2")
fig.legend(handles=[lines[0],lines[2]], labels=["0","2"], loc=3, title="legend 3")
```